# What is the vmlinuz.old file and what does it do ? What would happen if I deleted it?

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems

[image]this is the screenshot of my '/' directory .
PS : I'm kinda new to the linux environment .

Comment: Please don't use images of text. And what screen shot?

Comment: Note removing random system-file, because you don't know what they do is a sure way to break your system. The only things you should change is maybe add content to `/opt`, add content to `/usr/local`, edit some of `/etc` (but know what you are doing, get advice), and best to use tools to do the changes where possible.

Comment: As a general rule, you're unlikely to break something by deleting a file ending `.old`, you might however make recovering a broken system much more difficult / impossible since these files are generally a backup of the last version of something else.

Answer (score 5):

Historically, several Unix-style operating systems had their "current" kernel version as `/vmunix` and the "previous" version (for fallback in case of problems) as `/vmunix.old`. Linux originally adopted the similar convention, but with `linux` instead of `unix` and replacing the last character with `z` to indicate the kernel was compressed.

In many distributions, `/vmlinuz` and `/vmlinuz.old` are just symbolic links pointing to actual kernel files in `/boot`. In most cases they are not really used for anything any more: the common GRUB bootloaders `grub-mkconfig` (or `update-grub`) doesn't use those links at all, but looks at `/boot` directly when building up the bootloader configuration file.

But someone using a non-default bootloader might still be using those links; symbolic links take up an absolutely tiny amount of space; and keeping them up to date is not a big deal at all for the kernel installation/removal scripts. So, basically, it's a historical remnant that does not hurt anything and might still help someone somewhere.

If they are symbolic links, you could just delete them and probably have no problems at all. They might even re-appear automatically whenever you install a kernel update.

Comment: Yes.  Might be worth mentioning that if these are symbolic links then if you do remove them the next system upgrade is likely to add them back because, as already mentioned, the installation scripts maintain them.

Answer (score 0):

also new to linux, but vmlinuz is related to the linux kernel. afak. Maybe you have updatet linux-mint, or you have more linux kernel-images. so do I. I would not recommend deleting the vmlinuz.old file. (but I will try on my virtual machine and tell you if it breaks)

This should be a comment, Sorry I can not comment to questions